# Does Azure AD authentication work with Windows installer app?

Tags: azure-active-directory, windows-installer, claims-based-identity

I have a web application, where I authenticate user using Azure AD (Microsoft Entra ID) and retrieve the app role in my code.

The application is also configured to work offline by installing it on the computer - using Windows installer. My application works fine when used offline, except for retrieving the claims (app role) part.

I would like to know if Azure AD authentication work with desktop app (`.msi` installed on desktop)? Because when the application is installed and used offline, it does not return app role part of my code.

This is my code - `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState,
CustomUserAccount>(options =>   
{    
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ServerApi")["Scopes"]);
    options.ProviderOptions.Cache.CacheLocation = "localStorage";
    options.ProviderOptions.Cache.StoreAuthStateInCookie = true;

    options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "appRole";
}).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState,
CustomUserAccount, CustomAccountFactory>();
```

`CustomAccountFactory`:

```
public class CustomAccountFactory : AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserAccount>
{
    public CustomAccountFactory(IAccessTokenProviderAccessor accessor)
        : base(accessor)
    {
    }

    public async override ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(CustomUserAccount account,
        RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
    {
        var initialUser = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);

        if (initialUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
        {
            var userIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)initialUser.Identity;

            foreach (var role in account.Roles)
            {
                 userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("appRole", role));
            }
        }

        return initialUser;
    }
}
```

I want the desktop app to return 'app role' claim. Thank you.